# Run postfix pipe command under a different user than nobody

Tags: postfix

I'm currently setting up e-mail piping to a PHP script in a directory not accessible by others (it's set to 750). Postfix runs the pipe command under the user 'nobody', who naturally won't be able to access the script. I'm a bit hesitant in adding execute permissions to that folder, since I don't want other users to be able to access it (even if they don't know the path). So, what I do want, is to have the pipe command run under a different user, that does have access to that folder.

The server I want to do this on has Virtualmin installed. I've set everything up with Virtualmin, including the alias that is fed to the PHP script. There's several threads on the Virtualmin forum about this issue, but there's no solution there yet other than making the folder executable by others.

So, how can I let the pipe command run under a different user than nobody?

Comment: `cmd1 | sudo -u otheruser cmd2`, if you setup sudo to allow nobody to run cmd2.

Answer (score 3):

[**As documented**](http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html), `pipe(8)` can execute as any user you tell it to - except root.
That, and *only* that, will execute as `nobody`.

```
yourscript unix - - n - - pipe user=<uid> argv=<yourexecutable>
```

The `user=` takes any existing unix user, and runs the pipe(8) instance under those credentials.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It doesn't completely answer my question, though. How do I "link" (for the lack of a better word) my alias to that command? So when an e-mail is sent to support@example.com, that specific command gets executed? I've already got an alias in /etc/aliases which looks like: support-example.com: "|php -q /home/user/public_html/subfolder/script.php".

Comment: If you alias that to the user you want the script to run under, you can then pipe it to PHP in their .forward file.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the user in which Postfix runs for piping is by default nobody.

That line changes the user under which piping runs and you should be aware that in the Postfix documentation it warns about this:
DO NOT SPECIFY A PRIVILEGED USER OR THE POSTFIX OWNER

Just be aware of the security implications of piping emails via a privileged user on the server.

Answer (score 0):

This was just brought up over on StackOverflow a few days ago, with slightly different wording, but the problem is the same and the solution is the same:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28923771/virtualmin-feed-to-program-cant-open-file/28934181

In short, the solution is to login to Usermin as the user you need to pipe as, and create the pipe there. Virtualmin *does* setup users to run things as the user when piped from Postfix, but not in the context of Virtualmin...only when you create them under Usermin.

You can also create the pipe manually within the .procmailrc of the user in question.