# Run incoming mail through PHP script - Postfix

Tags: php, postfix, centos8

I have followed this answer [Pipe all Postfix email for a domain to PHP script - Centos7/EC2](https://serverfault.com/questions/881096/pipe-all-postfix-email-for-a-domain-to-php-script-centos7-ec2) to direct incoming mail for a specific address to a PHP script.

My aliases file entry looks like:

```
mail-incoming-php: "/usr/bin/php -q /var/spool/mail/php/incoming.php"
```

And the Postfix virtual file maps the e-mail address to

```
mail-incoming-php@localhost
```

My current test PHP script is set to create an empty file, which I have tested. When sending mail to the address in question the PHP script does not create a file, and the `maillog` contains this error:

```
cannot append message to file /usr/bin/php -q /var/spool/mail/php/incoming.php: cannot create file exclusively: No such file or directory
```

I have temporarily set the PHP script's permission to 777 and get the same error.

Maybe this is not the best way to solve this problem or something else needs doing?

All I need the script to do is read the contents of the incoming e-mail, the e-mail doesn't have to be relayed after this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike in the linked question, you are **not piping** the mail to the script, i.e.

```
mail-incoming-php: "| /usr/bin/php -q /var/spool/mail/php/incoming.php"
```

Because you are missing the `|` you are trying to write (append) to a file, instead:

- `/usr/bin/php -q /var/spool/mail/php/incoming.php` is an invalid path.
- `/usr/bin/php` would be appending the message to the PHP binary.
  (Luckily there's no permission for that!)
- `/var/spool/mail/php/incoming.php` would be appending to the script.

Also, you shouldn't have the script globally writable `777`, but (at most) `755`.

Comment: I had tried it like that initially, I have put it back and indeed maillog looks better e.g delivered to command:  /usr/bin/php -q /var/spool/mail/php/incoming.php... but still the PHP file has not created the file. Is there some way I can log the execution of the PHP script?

Comment: Don't worry, it was the parent directory permissions not being correct. Do you know what user will be running the PHP script?

Comment: By default it's run as user `nobody`, but you can change it. See e.g. https://serverfault.com/a/453438/274176